# Do I need to design background for each device size?

Tags: android

Dear All I’m going to work in android application I should design the interface. I read articles on http://developer.android.com/design/index.html  but I still have some missing point.
Do I need to design back ground for each device size ?

Comment: try using 9patch images http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html for   background..

Comment: You need to design the view according to the requirement that is for which devices you are designing the your app then according to that you need to prepare screens for app. If you are preparing app for multiple screens then according that you need to design. For that Go through the following [Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) [How to support multiple screens](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/07/how-to-support-multiple-screen-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check for this [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for supporting multiple screen. This link will show you how to create the different layout for different screen size devices.

*But even if you want to make a Unique layout for supporting multiple screen in orientation or portrait mode then,*

```
For image, use 9 patch images.
```

Here is the link http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

**For width and height of any widgets, use wrap_content or match_parent or you can use `android:layout_weight` and `android:weightSum`**

Avoid using the `pixels i.e. px`
 Use **dp**

**By this you can create the unique layout working for multiple screens, but that screen should be in orientation or portrait mode.**

*`If you want to support for for both,then you have to create`**`layout-land`**`for landscape mode in the res folder`*.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should. There are 4 main screen sizes in android those get layout xmls from res/layout-xlarge, res/layout-large, res/layout-normal and res/layout-small. At the same time, you should use different image resolutions for different screens those get images from drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-ldpi.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the background type. If your background is an image with high resolution you should provide different images for different screen sizes if the whole background is an image.
You can also:

- Make background from tiles (like [icloud.com](https://www.icloud.com/))
- Specify a [ninepatch image](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) if your image is something like a frame where corners should remain the same and the body should be scaled (not very good if you have some picture)
- [Specify multiple different images for different screen resolutions and densities.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) To do so read [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html). If you need even more precision in image scaling and quality you can use the fundamental size of screen attribute which is `sw<N>dp` - you can specify the smallest width of the screen where your image should be used. This is a qualifier name for a resource folder.

Some values you might use here for common screen sizes:

- 320, for devices with screen configurations such as:

  1. 240x320 ldpi (QVGA handset)
  2. 320x480 mdpi (handset)
  3. 480x800 hdpi (high density handset)
- 480, for screens such as 480x800 mdpi (tablet/handset).
- 600, for screens such as 600x1024 mdpi (7" tablet).
- 720, for screens such as 720x1280 mdpi (10" tablet).

You should also have a look at other [qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) that make Android choosing image at runtime (screen density, Available width, Available height, Screen size or Screen aspect). By combining these qualifiers and testing carefully you will be sure that the user has the best experience on each device.